Pass variable value to another function
I have a login and view message function on my app. I wanted to pass the users' id from check_username to get_entries where I can use it to filter the rows. But I don't know how to pass the id. Here is my code.
database_handler.py
def check_username(username, password):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result

def get_entries():
    id = // 
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM entrymonitoring WHERE student_id = (SELECT mystudent FROM parent_mystudent WHERE parent = {id}) ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 6"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results

LoginScreen.py
class LoginScreen(MDScreen):
    def login(self):
        # fetch login credentials
        username = self.ids.username.text
        password = self.ids.password.text

        # check if the credentials are valid
        login_check = database_handler.check_username(username, password)

        if login_check:
            Snackbar(text="Login successful").open()
        else:
            Snackbar(text="invalid username/password").open()

PublicScreen.py
class PublicScreen(MDScreen):
    def load_posts(self):
        self.ids.posts.clear_widgets()
        entry = database_handler.get_entries()

        for msg in entry:
            msg_card = MDCard(
                orientation="vertical",
                padding="20dp",
                size_hint=[None, None],
                size=["500dp", "120dp"],
                pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            )

            msg_title = MDLabel(
                halign="left",
                text="AMSAI",
                theme_text_color="Secondary",
                size_hint_y=None,
                height="40dp"
            )

            title_separator = MDSeparator(
                height="1dp"
            )

            msg_body = MDLabel(
                halign="left",
                text="Your student exited the school grounds at " + str(msg[2]),
            )

            msg_timestamp = MDLabel(
                text=str(msg[3]),
                halign="right",
                theme_text_color="Secondary",
                size_hint_y=None,
                height="5dp"
            )

            msg_card.add_widget(msg_title)
            msg_card.add_widget(title_separator)
            msg_card.add_widget(msg_body)
            msg_card.add_widget(msg_timestamp)

            self.ids.posts.add_widget(msg_card)

Can somebody help me on this one?

your get_username and get_entries functions are vulnerable to SQL-injections

@Aemyl Any other way to get those values? I'm totally noob, I'm so used doing this in Django, where I can just access them on session.

first you have to define function with parameter def get_entries(id): and later use it with parameter get_entries(some_value)

to keep ID and have access to this id in other functions then you should rather use self. in self.login_check

if you need ID in function in other class then you may have to send it as argument def load_posts(self, user_id):

Maybe it would be simpler to create global variable (outside classes) to keep user's data login_check - and then you can access it in any place in code.

Welcome to SO. Do a bit of search before posting questions like this, and give only minimum reproducible example [MRE], not your actual code. See this SO guideline  SO is becoming unusable day by day...info overflow, rather than helping.

to make code safer you should use ? (or maybe %) in SQL and later run cursor.execute(sql, (username, pasword))

To make the first comment clearer: See what the user name admin"-- would generate as SQL.

@AkshayVilasPatil OP doesn't use Django but Kivy - so inbuilt django authentication can be useless :/

because you import classes from other files so it may need to send global variable to every class as parameter - ie. def __init__(self, ..., user_data): self.user_data = user_data. Eventually you may keep data in App class and other classes should have function/variable self.parent to access data in App. Sometimes it may need self.parent.parent when you have nested widget.
